# How to disable Ubuntu control of fan speed

Tags: fan, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors, gigabyte

I have dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04, kernel version: 5.17.5-051705-generic and Windows 10.
When using Windows, the fans work silently, while in the case of Ubuntu, it seems that they are set to the maximum speed. In both cases, system is not under load.

I tried to verify what's happening with sensors, but I/O chip of my motherboard (Gigabyte Z690 Gaming X) is not supported by sensors-detect:

```
Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8689
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
```

Sensors output:

```
xxxx@xxxx-pc:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +31.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 8:        +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 12:       +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 16:       +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 20:       +25.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 28:       +25.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 29:       +25.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 30:       +25.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 31:       +25.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +16.8°C  (crit = +20.8°C)
temp2:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1787 RPM
temp1:        +37.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +40.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +79.8°C)
                       (crit = +81.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +40.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

I have configured fan speed slope in UEFI and the behaviour under Windows is consistent with it, so I'm trying to understand what happens that Ubuntu somehow "overrides" it.

How is this possible and how can I prevent it?

EDIT:
Problem occurs also on Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15, but doesn't on Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.13

Comment: You might have some luck getting the sensors working with help from this thread https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/154

Answer (score 1):

I feel dumb, but I resolved the problem. It turned out that it was't the fans connected to the motherboard that caused the noise, but the GPU ones. After installing Nvidia drivers (instead of nouveau), GPU fans don't reach high speeds without load.

Comment: My NVIDIA GF108 [GeForce GT 630] fan is very strong, and keeps running even after suspend!! Even running at 40 Celsius (high is 95). Nouveau is not my friend.